# Improve the Percentage of Post Explanation in the Profile's Top Tags

Tags: feature-request

Just one basic suggestion, I would like to have a message tooltip, on mouse hover (or something like this), for the `post %` showed in the profile section for the `top tags` of a user. This is because it cost me to figure out what was the meaning of this percentage.

After some searching, I got with the explanation that this percentage is related to the *percentage of posts under the related tag over the total posts made by the user*. So, displaying something like the next message on a tooltip text will be useful.

> N % of your posts are under this tag

What do you think about this?

Comment: @MarkAmery that was just an example of a tooltip description. Anyway, i have updated it for a more accurate one.